# Save time in a 6 nested for loop code

Tags: r, optimization, time

I'm trying to find the right parameters for my code, which is a backtrack of an Extended Kalman Filter. I have 6 nested for loops, one for each parameter. Currently when I have 3 possible values for each parameter, the code on average takes about 5 mins to run, but seeing that as I increase the number of parameter, my time taken would increase as n^6. I'm a bit worried.

Is there any way I can optimize the code to save more time?

PS - Just use any data file instead of the given Reddy.csv(1180 rows of data)
PPS - In the end I need to find the i,j,k,l,m,n values for the minimum MSE.

Here's the code:

```
start.time <- Sys.time()

library(invgamma)
w = read.csv("Reddy.csv")
q = ts(w[2])
num = length(q)

f = function(x){
  f1 = sqrt(x)
  return(f1)
}
h = function(x){
  h1 = x**3
  return(h1)
}


ae1 = seq(24,26,0.1)
ae2 = seq(24,26,0.1)

be1 = seq(0.1,2,0.1)
be2 = seq(0.1,2,0.1)

a = seq(1,3,0.1)
b = seq(0.1,2,0.1)

count = 0

MSE = matrix(nrow = length(ae1)*length(ae2)*length(be1)*length(be2)*length(a)*length(b), ncol =7)

for (i in ae1){
  for (j in ae2){
    for (k in be1){
      for (l in be2){
        for (m in a){
          for (n in b){
            d = rep(0,num)
            xt = rep(0,num)
            yt = rep(0,num)
            fx = rep(0,num)
            hx = rep(0,num)

            e = rinvgamma(num,i,k)
            g = rinvgamma(num,j,l)
            for(o in 2:num){
              fx[o] = f(xt[o-1])
              xt[o] = m*fx[o] + e[o-1]
              hx[o] = h(xt[o])
              yt[o]= n*hx[o] +g[o]
              d[o] = (yt[o] - q[o])**2
            }
            count <- count + 1
            MSE[count,1] = mean(d)
            MSE[count,2] = i
            MSE[count,3] = j
            MSE[count,4] = k
            MSE[count,5] = l
            MSE[count,6] = m
            MSE[count,7] = n
            t = rbind(mean(d),i,j,k,l,m,n)
            print(t)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken

m = which.min(MSE[,1])
MSE[m,]
```

Comment: For each o=2:num, you reset xt, yt, fx, hx to 0. Is this really what you want to do?

Comment: I didn't realize that. Thanks. I'll fix that, by moving xt,yt,fx and hx to above the for "o" loop

Comment: @Consistency Thanks a lot - it actually brought down the run time from 5 minutes to 7 seconds. Thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome. And `print` usually takes some time if doing repeatedly. So maybe `t = rbind(mean(d),i,j,k,l,m,n)` and `print(t)` can be removed from the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further optimizations can be achieved by vectorizing some of the most inner loop computation like this,

```
start.time <- Sys.time()

library(invgamma)
w = rnorm(1180)
q = ts(w)
num = length(q)

f = function(x){
    f1 = sqrt(x)
    return(f1)
}
h = function(x){
    h1 = x**3
    return(h1)
}


ae1 = seq(24,26,1)
ae2 = seq(24,26,1)

be1 = seq(0.1,2,0.7)
be2 = seq(0.1,2,0.7)

a = seq(1,3,1)
b = seq(0.1,2,0.7)

count = 0

MSE = matrix(nrow = length(ae1)*length(ae2)*length(be1)*length(be2)*length(a)*length(b), ncol =7)

for (i in ae1){
    for (j in ae2){
        for (k in be1){
            for (l in be2){
                for (m in a){
                    for (n in b){
                        d = rep(0,num)
                        xt = rep(0,num)
                        yt = rep(0,num)
                        fx = rep(0,num)
                        hx = rep(0,num)
                        e = rinvgamma(num,i,k)
                        g = rinvgamma(num,j,l)
                        for(o in 2:num){
                            fx[o] = f(xt[o-1])
                            xt[o] = m*fx[o] + e[o-1]
                        }
                        hx = h(xt)
                        yt = n*hx +g
                        d = (yt - q)**2

                        count <- count + 1
                        MSE[count,1] = mean(d)
                        MSE[count,2] = i
                        MSE[count,3] = j
                        MSE[count,4] = k
                        MSE[count,5] = l
                        MSE[count,6] = m
                        MSE[count,7] = n
                        ## t = rbind(mean(d),i,j,k,l,m,n)
                        ## print(t)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken

m = which.min(MSE[,1])
MSE[m,]
```

On my laptop, this can make the code several times faster.

Edit:

If the combinations are too many, and you don't want to have the large matrix created and modified, since you only care about the minimum of MSE, you can only keep record of the best combination like this:

```
MSEopt <- Inf

for (i in ae1){
    for (j in ae2){
        for (k in be1){
            for (l in be2){
                for (m in a){
                    for (n in b){
                        d = rep(0,num)
                        xt = rep(0,num)
                        yt = rep(0,num)
                        fx = rep(0,num)
                        hx = rep(0,num)
                        e = rinvgamma(num,i,k)
                        g = rinvgamma(num,j,l)
                        for(o in 2:num){
                            fx[o] = f(xt[o-1])
                            xt[o] = m*fx[o] + e[o-1]
                        }
                        hx = h(xt)
                        yt = n*hx +g
                        d = (yt - q)**2

                        if (mean(d) < MSEopt) {
                            ## print(MSEopt)
                            MSEopt <- mean(d)
                            best_combn <- list(i = i, j = j, k = k, l = l, m = m, n = n)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This cut down the time required even more.
When I add a big range of values for the 6 parameters, the matrix doesn't get made "because it is too large". Is there anyway to circumvent this problem?

Comment: @AVT If the matrix is too large, maybe you can only keep record of the minimum of MSE like my edit on the answer.

Comment: But then I wouldn't know which parameters minimised the MSE.

Comment: @AVT Look my code, when the MSE is smaller than before, you can save the best combination in some variable like `best_combn` in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. This sped up the program as well!!